# Dialog se repite dos veces C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tsql

Buenas tardes, saludos.

Ultimamente he tenido un problema con el muestreo de un Dialog en un formload, actualmente estoy empleando C# en conjunto con sql server e implementado la UI de mi programa con Mahapps.metro. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 private async void formload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Title = "Menú Principal " + "(Sesión de: " + MainWindow.cuentalogueada + ")";
        notificaciones.ToolTip = "Tienes reportes pendientes";
        datagrid.IsReadOnly = true;
        bool estado = await conex.ocupado(this);
        if (estado == true && banderanotificaciones == false)
        { 
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Tienes reportes pendientes", "Puedes corroborarlas en el botón de la esquina inferior derecha.");

        }
        else
            if (estado == false && banderanotificaciones == true || estado == false && banderanotificaciones == false)
        {
            notificaciones.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }


    }
```

Mientras tanto, la funcion ocupado se encuentra dentro de una clase, el procedimiento que realiza es la siguiente:

```
public async Task<bool> ocupado(MetroWindow ventana) 
    {
        bool ocupado = false;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select encargados from reportes where encargados like '" + '%' + MainWindow.cuentalogueada + '%' + "' and estado = 'Abierto' ",cn);
            lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (lector.Read())
                ocupado = true;
            else
            { }
            lector.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            await ventana.ShowMessageAsync("Hubo un error grave en la base de datos: ", Ex.ToString());
            Application.Current.Shutdown(); 
        }
        return ocupado;
    }
```

He aquí el problema; siempre que logueo a algún usuario cuyas condiciones cumplan con las anteriores, se me muestra el dialog (aquí todo bien), sin embargo, siempre se muestra dos veces.

PD: Recién use trace y me he podido dar cuenta que es debido a que el formload se esta disparando dos veces, sin importar que sea asincronico o no.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: En mi experiencia, cuando el "form" sale de primer plano es descargado, luego al cerrar lo que está encima se vuelve a cargar, similar a lo que ocurre con los tabs de un TabControl, al cambiar de tab, incluso los ya cargados, el contenido de estos vuelve a disparar su evento LOAD, por algún motivo tu ventana sale de plano, tal vez por el mensaje que muestras, y luego al cerrarlo vuelve a cargar la ventana.. 

Para salir del paso puedes usar un bool que verifique si la comprobación ya se hizo o aún no para el usuario que logueas, ya que LOAD puede dispararse mas de 1 vez.. no solo 1.

Comment: Coincido contigo Leonardo, he testeado lo que mencionas, y efectivamente fue asi, la forma salia de plano cada vez que se daba este anuncio, por lo que se disparaba de nuevo su evento load; sin embargo logre solucionarlo empleando una variable estatica en la forma en donde estaba el menu de logueo, y con la cual procedí a hacer la comparación (en la misma forma de logueo) para que ya unicamente se mostrara el mensaje en la forma siguiente sin necesidad de haber algo en su load.

Comment: Excelente entonces..